# UUID converter doesn't register

Tags: java, simple-framework

I have 3 classes. Folder, Notebook and a Base class.

```
public abstract class NotebookBase {
    @Attribute(name = "name") String mName;
    @Attribute(required = false) UUID mUuid;
}

public class NotebookFolder extends NotebookBase{
     @ElementListUnion({
         @ElementList(name = "folder", type = NotebookFolder.class, inline = true, required = false),
         @ElementList(name = "notebook", type = Notebook.class, inline = true, required = false)})
     private List<NotebookBase> mChildren = new ArrayList<NotebookBase>();
}

public class Notebook extends NotebookBase {
     @Attribute (name = "page_count") private int mPageCount = 0;
}
```

and a simple Converter:

```
public class UuidConverter implements Converter<UUID>{
    @Override
    public UUID read(InputNode node) throws Exception
    {
        return UUID.fromString(node.getAttribute("id").getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, UUID value) throws Exception
    {
        node.setAttribute("id", value.toString());
    }
}
```

I have tried registering the Converter as described in the [tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters).

```
Registry registry = new Registry();
Strategy strategy = new RegistryStrategy(registry);
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

registry.bind(UUID.class, UuidConverter.class);
```

I tried to serialize an instance of a Folder and its subfolders and notebooks, but the output is empty.

I have put breakpoints in my Converter and is not being called at all.

The only way of making it work is to change

```
@Attribute(name="id") UUID mUuid;
//to
@Element(name="id") UUID mUuid;
```

but that blows up the xml

```
<folder name="documents">
   <folder name="Maths">
      <mUuid>
         <mostSigBits>8900925522479825724</mostSigBits>
         <leastSigBits>-8963928029250572835</leastSigBits>
      </mUuid>
      <folder name="Exams">
         <mUuid>
            <mostSigBits>3462229032913685898</mostSigBits>
            <leastSigBits>-5566328454854271064</leastSigBits>
         </mUuid>
         <notebook name="Exam1" page_count="11">
            <mUuid>
               <mostSigBits>-5326841338587362547</mostSigBits>
               <leastSigBits>-7556397486665814697</leastSigBits>
            </mUuid>
         </notebook>
   </folder>
</folder>
```

I would much rather have UUID as an attribute and not element like so:

```
<folder name="documents">
   <folder name="Maths" id="7b86709a-839e-433c-8399-baf3485a2ddd">
      <folder name="Exams" id="300c4ef6-35dd-4d8a-b2c0-6dc311431fa8">
         <notebook name="Exam1" id="b6134206-7ea2-4b0d-9722-488579a12d57" page_count="11"/>
   </folder>
</folder>
```

Comment: Could you provide more complete code snippets? It seems you have serialized a collection of articles in the first case while on the second case you have serialized a single article instance.

Comment: Updated it with some more code

Comment: Haved you tested an annotationstrategy for your Converter?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I see that you are doing wrong are as follows:

First when declaring the attribute in your code you need to declare your converter at the same time:

```
public abstract class NotebookBase {
...

@Attribute(required = false) 
@Convert(UuidConverter.class)
UUID mUuid;
```

}

Second, in your converter, the getAttribute function returns the value of the attrubute, calling the getValue() on that implies an element, so the correct code should look something like this:

```
public class UuidConverter implements Converter<UUID>{
@Override
public UUID read(InputNode node) throws Exception
{
    return UUID.fromString(node.getAttribute("id"));
}
```